# Asp. Net set default page instead of typed url page name

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.Net if some one try  to copy or typed url pages it will opened but how can set to open default page instead of typed url page name

Comment: This question is Unsalvageable - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21123923)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like setting a session variable on the default page.
`Session["VisitedDefaultPage"] = "Yes";`

Then on every other page, if `Session["VisitedDefaultPage"] != "Yes"` then redirect them back to the default page using `Response.Redirect("url/of/default/page.aspx");`